# Forbidding programs from stealing the focus

Tags: windows-7

I am looking for a program that can forbid programs from [stealing focus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focus_stealing) on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. Free is better, but I am OK to pay for it.

Comment: I don't think you ca find good solution for it. I remember when I tried to prevent this caused with some USB Wifi dongle. Luckily my problem was solvable.